# How do I append on to the array in the while loop: $rows[] = $row;?

Tags: php, mysqli

I need help, I tried myself to the fetched rows but cannot to get it appended on to the array in the `while` loop: `$rows[] = $row;` then try to  just build up the `$rows array` then output in the foreach later.

How do i do this?

```
 <?php
    $query = $dbc->query('SELECT * FROM customer');
    $rows = array();
    while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row['clientid'].' '.$row['inital'].' '.$row['firstname'].' '.$row['lastname'].' '.$row['mobile'].' '.$row['landline'].' '.$row['email'].' '.$row['address'].' '.$row['postcode'];
    }
 foreach ($rows as $row) { 
 ?>
  <td><?php $row['clientid']; ?></td>
  <td><?php $row['inital']; ?></td> 
  <td><?php $row['firstname']; ?></td>
  <td><?php $row['lastname']; ?></td>
  <td><?php $row['mobile']; ?></td>
  <td><?php $row['landline']; ?></td>
  <td><?php $row['email']; ?></td>
  <td><?php $row['address']; ?></td>
  <td><?php $row['postcode']; ?></td>
  </td>
  <?php } ?>
```

Eventually I did it this way,

```
   <?php
  $query = $dbc->query('SELECT * FROM customer');
if ( mysqli_num_rows( $query ) > 0 )
{
  while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $query, MYSQLI_ASSOC ))
  {
 echo "<tr><td>".$row['clientid']."</td><td>".$row['inital']."</td><td>".$row['firstname']."</td><td>".$row['lastname']."</td><td>".$row['mobile']."</td><td>".$row['landline']."</td><td>".$row['email']."</td><td>".$row['address']."</td><td>".$row['postcode']."</td></tr>";
  }
  echo '</tbody></table>' ;
}
else { echo '<div class="alert alert-error">
There are currently no records.
</div>' ; }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable $rows is initialized as an array, but is not being used.

```
while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
```

This will create an array of all your $row

Comment: so is it like this ` $query = $dbc->query('SELECT * FROM customer');
        $rows = array(); while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) 
  {  $rows[] = $row;
  
            echo $row['clientid'].' '.$row['inital'].' '.$row['firstname'].' '.$row['lastname'].' '.$row['mobile'].' '.$row['landline'].' '.$row['email'].' '.$row['address'].' '.$row['postcode'].' '.$row['accessibility'];
        }
foreach($rows as $row)`

Comment: Yes.  Of course you could make it more efficient, by combining the while loop with the foreach loop, since you're basically going through the list of rows, twice.

Comment: It's not liking the `<td>` etc

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you want all records in $rows & use foreach redundantly two times still you can do like,

```
$rows = array();
while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
   $rows[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: I want to style the `$rows` with `<td>` and `</td>`

Answer (score 0):

Please use enter and tab.

Also, why do you want to build the rows array? fetch_assoc does that for you

```
<?php while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) { ?> 
    <td><?php echo $row['clientid']; ?></td> 
    <td><?php echo $row['inital']; ?></td> 
    <td><?php echo $row['firstname']; ?></td> 
    <td><?php echo $row['lastname']; ?></td> 
    <td><?php echo $row['mobile']; ?></td> 
    <td><?php echo $row['landline']; ?></td> 
    <td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td> 
    <td><?php echo $row['address']; ?></td> 
    <td><?php echo $row['postcode']; ?></td> 
    <td><?php echo $row['accessibility']; ?></td> 
<?php } ?>
```

Or, if you want to do it in 2 steps

```
$rows = $query->fetch_all();

...

<?php foreach ($rows as $row) { ?> 
    <td><?php echo $row['clientid']; ?></td> 
    <td><?php echo $row['inital']; ?></td> 
    <td><?php echo $row['firstname']; ?></td> 
    <td><?php echo $row['lastname']; ?></td> 
    <td><?php echo $row['mobile']; ?></td> 
    <td><?php echo $row['landline']; ?></td> 
    <td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td> 
    <td><?php echo $row['address']; ?></td> 
    <td><?php echo $row['postcode']; ?></td> 
    <td><?php echo $row['accessibility']; ?></td> 
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: The first being echo is just for me to check it worked and it did than I needed to style the content so it is readable so it was suggested to me that I put all the `$row` into `$rows` which should help. For the second solution provided it does not work echoing the stuff out nor is it recommended by another person on here. Who do i follow? as northing works :( exclusing the first bit while ($row = `$query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $rows[] = $row;
    echo $row['clientid'].' '.$row['inital'].' '.$row['firstname'].' '.$row['lastname'].' '.$row['mobile'].' '.$row['landline'].' '.$row['email'];
}`

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question:

```
while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $rows[] = $row;
    echo $row['clientid'].' '.$row['inital'].' '.$row['firstname'].' '.$row['lastname'].' '.$row['mobile'].' '.$row['landline'].' '.$row['email'].' '.$row['address'].' '.$row['postcode'].' '.$row['accessibility'];
}
```

However, you may take another approach to this. Why not simply using the `while` loop to print the rows?

```
while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
?>
<td><?php $row['clientid']; ?></td>
<td><?php $row['inital']; ?></td> 
<td><?php $row['firstname']; ?></td>
<td><?php $row['lastname']; ?></td>
<td><?php $row['mobile']; ?></td>
<td><?php $row['landline']; ?></td>
<td><?php $row['email']; ?></td>
<td><?php $row['address']; ?></td>
<td><?php $row['postcode']; ?></td>
<td><?php $row['accessibility']; ?></td>
<?php } ?>
```

Or, if you just need the rows in an array, you can use [`fetchAll()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php), like this:

```
$rows = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: By the way, you are not `echo`ing the rows, so no value will be shown. ;)